# XSLTemplate in Mono

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mono, monodevelop

i have just comleted my project in c#.net and now the client has put up an horrible requirement that this application should be compatible with other Operating Systems as well such as Linux. So, i have to move towards mono development and i am using tool xamarin studio 4.0.12

The problem i am facing is about **xslTemplate** as mono does not support **MSXML2**. I have tried using **MSXML** but it does not contain **xslTemplate**.

What should i do? Can anyone help?

Comment: What is it you need to *do* ? Is `XslTransform` sufficient? IIRC that is fully implemented...

Comment: Marc Gravell, I want to apply an XSLT Stylesheet to an XML Document. I am also using Xsltransform method of MSXML2.

Comment: right; but *why* are you using `MSXML2` ? What is it that you need from there that isn't in the managed `XslTransform` implementation? Because *mono has one of those*. IIRC `MSXML2` is the unmanaged activex implementation, right?

Comment: Yes MSXML2 is the unmanaged activex. Marc Gravell, how i can use XslTransform then, i menas which libarary/assembly have XslTemplate in mono?

Comment: that would be the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform` class or the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` class, which I would expect to find in `System.Xml.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running an xsl[t] transformation over xml, you should be able to use either `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform` or `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` from `System.Xml.dll`. The API should be largely identical to the Microsoft implementations:

- [mono, `XslCompiledTransform`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform)
- [mono, `XslTransform`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aSystem.Xml.Xsl.XslTransform)
- [microsoft, `XslCompiledTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)
- [microsoft, `XslTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx)

Comment: @RizwanAnsari again, you keep asking about `XSLTemplate`, but that is an *implementation detail* of MSXML2. I asked you what you wanted to *do* - and you said "I want to apply an XSLT Stylesheet to an XML Document". That is what `XslTransform` and `XslCompiledTransform` ***do***. So either use *those*, or please be *very specific* what ***functionality*** it is you want that `XSLTemplate` offers, that these do not.